# Dynamically change column name in PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Is it possible pass a column name as parameter in a prepared MySQL statement? Take the following example:

```
UPDATE Images
SET :placement = :imageURL
WHERE ID = :titleID;
```

PDO adds `'` around each parameter, so the middle line above becomes:

```
SET 'Homepage' = '1.jpg'
```

Which MySQL doesn't like. Is there a way to include parameters for fieldnames in PDO statements and have them accepted?

Otherwise I guess I'll have to write several different PDO statements, depending on what's been chosen(?).

Comment: [Can I use a PDO prepared statement to bind an identifier (a table or field name) or a syntax keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991422)

Comment: @YourCommonSense - [working link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482104/can-i-use-a-pdo-prepared-statement-to-bind-an-identifier-a-table-or-field-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to do something like this:

```
$column = 'someColumn';

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE tableName SET {$column} = :columnValue WHERE ID = :recordId");
```

Parameterized placeholders are only for values.

I would suggest you read the comment @YourCommonSense posted on your question.

Answer (score 0):

In situations such as this, I use a different sort of replacement parameters, like so:

```
$unitLabel = 'store_number';
$sql = 'select * from users where [unitLabel] = :unit and level = :level;';
$sql = str_replace('[unitLabel]', $unitLabel, $sql);
$params = array(
  ':unit' => 300,
  ':level' => 'admin',
);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

The prepared SQL query ends up being processed (more or less) as:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE store_number = 300 AND level = 'admin';
```

Which works for my situation. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Is this vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: Not in my situation because the variables involved don't use values from tainted sources. Care must be taken with this method to make sure that any user input from *any* source be both validated and sanitized prior to use, but that should be instinctive for skilled programmers.

Comment: The way that I implemented this was I just used `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE {$var} = ?"` instead of using str_replace. I used an array of possible parameters and checked if `$var` existed there, if it did not, it killed the page. In your opinion, is this secure?