# update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to write an update query with PDO but it's not work

```
for ($count = 0; $count < 4; $count++) {
        if (!trim($elements[$count])=='') {

                $query = "update servers set " . '?' . "=" . '?' . "where " . '?'  . "=" . '?';
                $pdo = new PDO($db->dsn, 'adp', 'pass');
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $index[$count]);
                $stmt->bindParam(2, $elements[$count]);
                $stmt->bindParam(3, $index[$count]);
                $stmt->bindParam(4, $ServerName);
                $stmt->execute();
          }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Any errors, notices, ... something?

Comment: add field name in your query

Comment: you can't use parameters (i.e. `?`) as field names.

Comment: May be possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885091/dynamically-change-column-name-in-pdo-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182353/794119) for more details.