# Error: SQLSTATE[42000] When I try to update a value in a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''1235'='1235'
>   WHERE username='wafflezzz'' at line 1' in
>   /home/wafflez3/public_html/Project SA Theme/ipn/set.php:14 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/wafflez3/public_html/Project SA Theme/ipn/set.php(14):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/wafflez3/public_html/Project SA Theme/ipn/set.php on line 14

I get that error when I use this code to change a null value to a value.

```
    <?php session_start(); require "../pdo_connect.php"; $usrname = $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
<title>Loading...</title>
<?php
$checker = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE payer_user=:username AND success='1'");
$checker->bindParam(":username", $usrname);
$checker->execute();

while ($row = $checker->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

   $paidscript = $row["item_name"];
   $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET :script=:script WHERE username=:userr");
   $sql->bindParam(":userr", $usrname);
   $sql->bindParam(":script", $paidscript);
   $sql->execute();
    echo "You can now view the script!";




}
```

Comment: You sure it's not meant to be `$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET script=:script WHERE username=:userr");` ?

Comment: this line $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET :script=:script WHERE username=:userr");  remove ':' from script column name

Comment: its :script because I want to get the scriptname and my system works if u set the scriptname to the scriptname then u have the script. Ik its stupid but thats just how I did it. Also the scriptname gets a column

Comment: Simple: You can't do this `SET :script` it's called binding a column.

Comment: Why don't you just have a field called `scriptname` and have the script name in it?

Answer (score 1):

`$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET :script=:script WHERE username=:userr");`

Should probably be

`$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET script=:script WHERE username=:userr");`

You're simply not meant to bind field names to parameters. If you do, it will give you an error like this.

To have a dynamic field name, you would have to do something like:

```
$paidscript = $row["item_name"];
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET {$paidscript}=:script WHERE username=:userr");
```

Although you shouldn't really be entering a field dynamically if it's from a user inputted value.

Comment: How could I make :script=:script work, what else would I have to add

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885091/dynamically-change-column-name-in-pdo-statement . You cant bind parameters to field names.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET {$paidscript}=:script WHERE username=:userr");
```

Instead of this:

```
   $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE us SET :script=:script WHERE username=:userr");
```